# Populate elements with class name using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some HTML which looks like this

```
<p>Latte: <span class="hot-drink"></span></p>
<p>Capuccino: <span class="hot-drink"></span></p>
<p>Coca Cola: <span class="cold-drink"></span></p>
<p>Water: <span class="cold-drink"></span></p>
<p>Iced tea: <span class="cold-drink"></span></p>
```

I would like to use javascript to populate all of the `<span>` elements with the class `hot-drink` applied to them with the variable `hot-drink-status()`.

So far I have managed to do this to only one of the elements. The code I wrote looks like this:

```
var hot-drink = "Avaiable";
document.querySelectorAll('.hot-drink')[0].innerHTML = hot-drink;
```

I believe I need to change the `[0]` to something else. I have tried `[i]` but this does not work.

I know that `querySelectorAll` is working as it allows me to apply the script to any element. I am just unable to apply the script to all element.

The outcome I am looking for is the HTML to be rendered as below

```
<p>Latte: <span class="hot-drink">Available</span></p>
<p>Capuccino: <span class="hot-drink">Available</span></p>
<p>Coca Cola: <span class="cold-drink"></span></p>
<p>Water: <span class="cold-drink"></span></p>
<p>Iced tea: <span class="cold-drink"></span></p>
```

All elements with the class `hot-drink` are populated with the text "Available"

Comment: "have tried [i] but this does not work." ... please show that try instead of that pseudocode thats currently in your question...

Comment: What end-result are you looking for, what should the html/DOM become?

Comment: I have updated the question to include this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (do not use minus char in variable names - [camel case](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) instead)

```js
var hotDrink = 'Available';

document.querySelectorAll('.hot-drink').forEach(el=> el.innerHTML= hotDrink)
```

```html
<p>Latte: <span class="hot-drink"></span></p>
<p>Capuccino: <span class="hot-drink"></span></p>
<p>Coca Cola: <span class="cold-drink"></span></p>
<p>Water: <span class="cold-drink"></span></p>
<p>Iced tea: <span class="cold-drink"></span></p>
```

Comment: Any specific reason for using `[...document.querySelectorAll('.hot-drink')]` instead of `document.querySelectorAll('.hot-drink')` for applying the `forEach`. Basically they both would give you arrays.

Comment: @VarunSharma you are right - fixed (for `.map` it doesn't work, but for `.forEach` it works without `...` - thanks - I don't know it +3)